# Failing to deploy to a Sepolia network

Tags: contract-development, metamask, hardhat

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {},
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.8",
}
```

The code is returning the following error below

```
HardhatError: HH101: Hardhat was set to use chain id 11155111, but connected to a chain with id 1.
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider.request
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hardhat was set to use chain id 11155111, but connected to a chain with id 1

The error message here it pretty telling. The `SEPOLIA_RPC_URL` that you have in your env file is most likely a node endpoint for the Ethereum mainnet (chain id 1) instead of Sepolia (chain id 11155111).